# Does Minecraft PE have commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Are there any commands in Minecraft Pocket Edition? I'm looking for both singleplayer and multiplayer commands including admin commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about chat commands like `/spawn` and `/tpa`, some servers do support these commands using plugins. There was no functionality of this in Singleplayer or unmodded Multiplayer, but there is now because of the update.

Comment: What commands are in the update? I have the .14.b4 update and haven't seen any commands work for me.

Answer (score 7):

### Version 0.16 and later

[Support for some commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.16.0#Commands) was added with version 0.16 (October 2016).

### Version 0.15 and earlier

No. There is no command functionality, and it's possible that the commands code isn't even present in the program yet.

Answer (score 1):

if you hit chat and do / (command) some will work but so far when I try I get nothing but try with /gamemode and it will say command gamemode not found.

Comment: what kind of commands work? can u tell us any of them?

Answer (score 0):

At the present 0.15.10 update, commands in single player worlds are not yet supported. In 0.16.0 (the boss update) Mojang will add a few commands like `/time set` and `/kill`, etc. for more info go to Mojang's posts about it [here](https://mojang.com/2016/09/add-ons-ahoy-boss-update-coming-october-18/) and [here](https://mojang.com/2016/08/sneak-peek-boss-update-is-coming-to-pocket-and-windows-10/). I don't know all the commands they are adding in 0.16.0, but later in 0.17.0 or later they will probably add more commands. 0.16.0 will be released October 18, 2016, and I have heard that 0.17.0 might be released in November.