# If I type in any commands, I get an error

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft PE, I cannot type in any commands.  I put:

```
/time set 1500
/gamemode 0
/wand
/kill all mobs
```

And every time it says "Error Command".

What would I do?

Comment: You put all that as one command?

Comment: The last time I checked there were no commands in the PE version.

Comment: Also /wand isn't even a command of the PC version, it's part of a bukkit plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Minecraft PE have commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135363/does-minecraft-pe-have-commands)

Answer (score 5):

As of 0.10.5, no commands are implemented in Minecraft Pocket Edition.

Support for future commands was added in [0.7.4](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#A0.7.4), that is the game is theoretically capable of parsing commands, but no valid command exist.

> Added commands, however when attempting to use any command "Error: Command not found" displays.

Comment: My Version Of Minecraft is 3.6.10

Answer (score 0):

It might be saying error because of that command isn't supported in that version. You should try doing some research on commands and consoles to get an idea. Because I have tried some commands on PC that use to work and now don't. So I consider researching.

Comment: Sorry MrLemon I didn't notice you had said basically what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,the commands may be added in 0.11.0 but then there is no need for commands because you can then Change the gamemode and make it always day

Answer (score -1):

There are no commands in PE yet!

Comment: [Yes there is.](https://www.pocketmine.net/)

Answer (score -3):

In life bout you can use commands like
-/vip
-/hub
And more I've been resershing that on a
Server with other people it will work
Here's more
-/kill 
-/help
-/tell
-/version