# Can you use commands in Minecraft PE v0.7.1?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can you use commands in Minecraft PE v0.7.1? I've seen people do it but I don't seem to be able to. Do I have to have a specific device like an iPhone? I currently have an android tablet with:

- Android 4.5
- Core duo processors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Minecraft PE have commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135363/does-minecraft-pe-have-commands)

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft Pocket Edition Vanilla v0.7.1 does not have any commands. You may have seen someone on the PC version, or using a mod such as [this one](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-mods-tools/1987419-0-9-4-single-player-commands-v1-0-3-automatic), which adds some commands.