# Are there any commands for McPe v.0.15.0

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to make commands forever but the usual game mode and weather but they never work in any version

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same question

[Does Minecraft PE have commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135363/does-minecraft-pe-have-commands)

But I think nothing special has changed for commands yet

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Mojang/Microsoft are still working on it.

You can download mods and other things, but without mods, it isn't possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are NO commands in vanilla MCPE.

Nor any mods that enable commands at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft: Pocket Edition currently does not have any commands, although they presumably should have them soon. When you attempt to do a command, for example /give {Playername} {item} it will say:
*Error: Command give not found*