# Can you use commands in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found some commands on the Internet, but none work on MCPE 0.15.0. Can I use commands in MCPE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Minecraft PE have commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135363/does-minecraft-pe-have-commands)

Answer (score 2):

Commands were officially added in version 0.16.0 (0.15.9 for beta testers). [Minecraft PE Commands](https://mcpehq.com/faq/commands-available-minecraft-pe/)

Answer (score 1):

Without mods/cheats/plugins  it's not possible. You can do it on certain servers that support commands, but other than that you can't get commands in game without mods.

Although, in a recent update (0.16.1), they added (almost) all commands from the computer version to the mobile edition. So now you can use commands, assuming you have the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't without mods. But some say it'll be added in future update
http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Commands
"Commands are actions entered by the Player which
make a certain action occur in the game
automatically. Commands have been confirmed to be
added in a future update, but as of now, they can only
be accessed via Plugins .
Commands used to be the only way to obtain
Status Effects.
However, after Update 0.12.1 , some Status
Effects can be obtained by Potions.
Commands can be used in Multiplayer on certain
servers."

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/195502)

Comment: Sorry.. I'm new here

Comment: @LY3R1FF2.0 you wrote ALL that?

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: @LY3R1FF2.0 if you don't put it in block quotes, it implies you wrote all of it. At least, I think it does

Comment: @Alex I didn't know that. Anyways Thanks for the information really appreciate it I'm new. I don't know all the things.